# Puppet : How to use service with schedule

Tags: puppet

I would like to schedule a service restart during a certain period (schedule).
I have attempted a number of variations but none have been successful. Hoping someone knows what I am doing wrong :

```
schedule { 'my_sched':
  range   => '11:00 - 11:20',
  period => daily,
  repeat => 1,
}

service { 'my_service':
  ensure    => 'running',
  enable    => true,
  schedule  => 'my_sched',
}
```

If I replace service with exec, it works fine.
If I replace schedule with a file dependency, it works as well.
But service does not work with schedule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained in the docs [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/schedule.html) that:

> Currently, **schedules can only be used to stop a resource from being applied**; they cannot cause a resource to be applied when it otherwise wouldn’t be, and they cannot accurately specify a time when a resource should run.

And that's the problem ; the service will already be running in your schedule, so Puppet will see that it is running and find there is nothing to do.

Maybe just use cron? I would get Puppet to install a cron job that restarts the service instead.

Comment: The OP should note in particular that *applying* a `Service` resource does not restart it; that's what *refreshing* it does.  Refreshing can happen only if the service is also being applied (so it is affected by schedules, too), but it only does happen if the service receives an event *during that catalog run*.  Thus, a schedule cannot be used to, say, defer a service restart from one catalog run to some later one.  If that's the objective, then it might work to `Exec` an `at` command at need to schedule the wanted restart.